# Redis Timeseries data - Millions of records in Hash and Sorted set

Tags: hash, redis, spring-data-redis, sortedset

I am trying to use redis as timeseries and in order to do that I am using Sorted sets and Hash.
Hash will store my domain object and sorted set will have reference to it with score as time. As I am getting records in millisec and have throughput around 300K/sec, what is the best way to write it faster on redis. From write side I have two below queries :

repository.save(data); //to store data object in hash using repository of spring data redis
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key,memberValue,data.getSourceTime()); // creating sorted set for hash reference as timestamp as member.

I am looking for a faster way to store this data.

Comment: Have you looked at [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)?

Comment: is there a reason why you _want_ it to be faster?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options beyond the classic sortedsets+hashes, Streams and RedisTimeSeries.

**RedisTimeSeries** - If your data is numeric (for example sensor data like temperature) you can store the a series inside a key without any additional work needed. 
Additional features:

- Compression built in to allow you to save space
- Automatic downsampling
- Query by labels of multiple keys

https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/

**Streams** - If you have a stream of events that are non-numeric and you don't care about any numeric based optimizations [some compression exists for same field input].

Both supports capping and ranged query.

https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/

*Disclosure: I initiated RedisTimeSeries project in redislabs.*

Comment: I can not use above solutions. I need a better way with redis without using timeseries and streams.

Comment: Can you explain why can't you use these options? What are your limitations?